# Google Analytics for iOS Missing Data in Ecommerce Hits

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am trying to integrate Google Analytics Ecommerce tracking with my iOS app, and it seems that Google Analytics is only picking up part of my data: I either get a Transaction with a total price of 0 but the item comes through, or I get a transaction with the correct total price, but no item. I am sending all transactions with a single item, with the same price as the total transaction price. This is the code I'm using to log the transaction (using the latest 2.0 beta 4 iOS SDK):

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker;
GAITransaction *transaction = [GAITransaction transactionWithId:transaction_id
                                                withAffiliation:nil];
NSString *category = nil; // This is sometimes set to a string value
int64_t price = [rate[@"total_price"] integerValue] * 1000000;
[transaction addItemWithCode:@"Code"
                        name:@"Name"
                    category:category
                 priceMicros:price
                    quantity:1];
transaction.revenueMicros = price;
transaction.shippingMicros = (int64_t)(0);
transaction.taxMicros = (int64_t)(0);
[tracker sendTransaction:transaction];
```

Both the js and Android SDKs are working fine, I'm only experiencing this problem with iOS. After examining the actual HTTP parameters being sent by the GA SDK, the only thing I can see that looks off is that both the `trans` and the `item` hits from the iOS SDK have the same `ht` value, which appears to be a timestamp in milliseconds. Is it possible GA's backend is uniquifying based on this value, and the iOS SDK is incorrectly sending two hits with the same `ht` value, or am I doing something else wrong?

Thanks.